# Combining same key's in an array and print it in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have $product array. Here is the sample data in the array.

```
[feature]=>[value]

[width]=> [100 m]
[method]=> [Nail Down]
[method]=> [Main Floor]
[Warranty]=> [25 years]
[Color]=> [Red]
[Color]=> [Blue]
```

I want to print the above data as

```
Width: 100m
method: Nail Down, Main Floor
Warranty: 25 years
Color: Red, Blue
Here is the smarty code i have
```

I have the following code.

```
foreach($product as $key=$Value){
       echo $key."=".$value.<br>;
 }
```

Please note that i don't want to generate another array and then print. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two values with the same key in array as in your example. Did you mean the value is an array? Such as `$product['method'] = ['Nail Down', 'Main Floor']`

If so you can use the following code:

```
echo $key."=" . (is_array($value) ? join(', ', $value) : $value) ."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple keys with differnet values in PHP. This means that you can't have such data in the sample array. That would become:

```
[feature]=>[value]

[width]=> [100 m]
[method]=> [Main Floor]
[Warranty]=> [25 years]
[Color]=> [Blue]
```

That's why you'll never achieve the goal. You should provide different keys for variations in your array.